# Prove f is holomorphic using morera's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

What kind of subdivisions must I use on an arbitrary triangle in D
[image]

I dont understand how the base is extended to coincide with L using continuity in the top 2 diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Say $T$ is a triangle in $D$. If $D\cap L=\emptyset$ then $$\int_{\partial T}f=0.$$
If $T\cap L\ne\emptyset$ you can use $L$ to divide $T$ into two polygons $P_1$ and $P_2$, in such a way that $$\int_{\partial T}f=\int_{P_1}f+\int_{P_2}f=0+0=0.$$

Comment: how do i do that , what are those 2 polygons ? and how do either of them  intersect  with L

Comment: can you check out my edit. i have specified where i have my doubt